# Excel/multiple reference criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In my code, I would like to check to see if Target Cell (A11) is matching in 3 different spreadsheet and return the appropriate value from the cell. So In manual way, I copy cell A11 and visit each one of datasheet tabs to see if the cell data is there or not. What I'm trying to do here is how to show "NOTHING" if reference cell is empty. With just single line of searching works as good as gold:

```
=IF(
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)="",
,"",
IF(
ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R41: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R42: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R43: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)))
```

but I wanted to do searching not just one, but all 3 spreadsheets so added OR function and made whole mess.. (that's all I can think of) I've battled with many hours but couldn't figured out yet. Here is my mess-up code!

```
=IF(OR(
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)="",
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)="",
VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)=""),"",
IF(
ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R41: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R42: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE))&"
"&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"","R43: " & VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE)))
```

Could you take a look and point me out where I need to fix my code please? Thanks:)

Comment: This question is better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: You said you want to show "NOTHING" if it isn't on any of the three sheets. What do you want to show if it *is* present in one of the sheets? How about two? All three sheets?

Comment: @AndreTerra Yeah I should've posted in the Super user haha.. BTW if Reference cell doesn't have anything then would like to see blank cell. Also if one present, return 1 item, if 2 present then 2 value returns. Also all 3 then, would like to do see all three. In short, only presented cell would like to return and return black cell if none. Thanks!

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,0),"")&IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,0),"")&IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,0),"")`

Answer (score 0):

If you have found a match but the cell to return a value is empty then typically you return a zero, the value of a blank cell. If you expect to return text then you can return a zero-length string (e.g. `""`, `TEXT(,)` or *nothing*) by appending a zero-length string to the return value.

```
vlookup($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000, 11 ,FALSE)&""
```

This returns a zero-length string if the cell to return is blank and does not affect the result if the cell to return contains text. It **does** however change a cell to return's numerical value to text-that-looks-like-a-number so be careful. There are other ways to deal with numbers that do not include turning them into text.

Since you are concatenating R41, R42 and R43 to the returned value from VLOOKUP anyways, all you should require is better error control. Your whole formula would benefit from the IFERROR function it seems.

```
=IFERROR("R41: "&VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 41'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE), "")&
 IFERROR("R42: "&VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 42'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE), "")&
 IFERROR("R43: "&VLOOKUP($A11,'[DataSheet]SOC 43'!$C$2:$P$5000,11,FALSE), "")
```

Now this may leave a **R41:** with nothing following it but without sample data together with expected results this is the best I can surmise from your narrative.